# Reinstantiate static constructor via Reflection

Tags: c#, static, system.reflection

Im using a 3rd party dll for some operations, the instance of the class is static and from time to time is crashing.
I was thinking if there is a way to reinstantiate the class via Reflection.

I used DotPeek to check the library and it looks something like this:

```
public class C_SomeWrapper
    {
        private static C_SomeWrapper _instance;
        public C_SomeWrapper()
        {
            InitStuff();
        }
        void InitStuff()
        {

        }
        public void Destroy()
        {
            C_SomeWrapper._instance = (C_SomeWrapper)null;
        }
        public static C_SomeWrapper Instanse
        {
            get
            {
                if (C_SomeWrapper._instance == null)
                    C_SomeWrapper._instance = new C_SomeWrapper();
                return C_SomeWrapper._instance;
            }
        }
    }
```

When i reference to it i do :

```
C_SomeWrapper _wrapper=C_SomeWrapper.Instanse
```

Since is crashing i would like to Destroy() and re-instantiate the constructor.
I was thinking maybe is posible to acces `_instance` and make it null via Reflection.
Id like to mention that just Destroy() doesnt work so probably i need to call the constructor and to InitStuff()
Any toughts on if its posible or not or maybe some alternatives

Thanks

Comment: "instance of the class is static" That is a oxymoron if I ever saw one. Fields and Functions are either Instance. Or static. They can not be both. Sometimes you might have a single instance case, wich might be what you actually mean. But there is a public constructor so it does not look like that.

Comment: Are you trying to call the static constructor a second time?  That seems like a _really_ bad idea; they are written with the idea that they only get called a single time.  If you (really) wanted to, you could probably set `C_SomeWrapper._instance` to `null` (via reflection) and then the next time someone accesses `C_SomeWrapper.Instanse`, the internal instance would get rebuilt.  Make sure **no one** is trying to access anything to do with the class when you do that.

Comment: Yes exactly , i want to call second, third an so on every time crashes, could you help me on how to do make Instanse =null  via reflection?

Comment: _and from time to time is crashing._ it sounds like you should maybe investigate that and figure out why. It seems like you are trying to duct tape over a bigger problem here.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to reset `C_SomeWrapper._instance` back to null and then let the existing code recreate an instance for you.  The example below does this (though it uses a different class name and field name).

I'm working with a type called `MyPrivateClass` that contains a nullable static field named `SomeField` (it's a class I had hanging around):

```
   var myType = typeof(MyPrivateClass);
   var anObject = new MyPrivateClass();

   var myField = myType.GetField("SomeField", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
   myField.SetValue(anObject, null);
```

At the end of that, the private field `anObject.SomeField` is null.

I wasn't sure how this might work for a class that is declared `static`.  However, it looks like `FieldInfo.SetValue(null, null)` will work for a static member.  As a result, you don't need to instantiate `anObject` (as shown above).

Comment: I tried as you sugest but for the var anObject = new MyPrivateClass(); it throws TargetInvocationException +  InnerException {"Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."} System.Exception {System.AccessViolationException}

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to Re-run a static constructor like so:

```
void Main()
{
    var t = typeof(AmStaticHearMeRoar);
    TryIt(t,RunConstructor);
    TryIt(t,RunTypeInitializer);
    TryIt(t, RunClassConstructor);
}

static void TryIt(Type t, Action<Type> f){
    Console.WriteLine("value is:" + AmStaticHearMeRoar.State);
    AmStaticHearMeRoar.Reset();
    try{
        f(t);
        Console.WriteLine("constructor rerun, value is:" + AmStaticHearMeRoar.State);
    } catch(Exception ex){
        ex.Dump();
        Console.WriteLine("constructor rerun?, value is:" + AmStaticHearMeRoar.State);
    }
    finally{
        AmStaticHearMeRoar.Reset();
    }

}

static void RunConstructor(Type t) {
    var m = t.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic, System.Type.DefaultBinder, System.Type.EmptyTypes, null);
    m.Dump();
    m.Invoke(new object[] {});
}
static void RunTypeInitializer(Type t){
    t.TypeInitializer.Invoke(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static, System.Type.DefaultBinder, new object[] {},System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture);
}
static void RunClassConstructor(Type t) {
    // only works if it hasn't been run =(
    RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(t.TypeHandle);
}
// Define other methods and classes here

public static class AmStaticHearMeRoar
{
    static int myStaticState;
    static AmStaticHearMeRoar()
    {
        myStaticState = 3;
    }
    public static void Reset() {
        myStaticState = 0;
    }
    public static int State => myStaticState;
}
```

see also [How do I invoke a static constructor with reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524906/how-do-i-invoke-a-static-constructor-with-reflection)

however 2 fail, the 3rd just knows the constructor was already run.