# Force static constructor to run multiple times

Tags: c#, reflection, static-constructor

This is supposedly [the way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2524938/9971404) to force a static constructor to run multiple times:

```cs
typeof(Foo).TypeInitializer.Invoke(null, null);
```

That does not work for me. See this [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VXGrYu), example which has this:

```cs
using System;

public static class Foo
{
    static Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("inside cctor");
    }

    public static void Run() { }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Foo.Run();                                      // runs cctor
        typeof(Foo).TypeInitializer.Invoke(null, null); // does not run cctor
        typeof(Foo).TypeInitializer.Invoke(null, null); // does not run cctor
        typeof(Foo).TypeInitializer.Invoke(null, null); // does not run cctor
    }
}
```

That prints "inside cctor" only once. I expected it to run multiple times.

Comment: I'm no Eric Lippert or Jon Skeet, but I can't imagine why you would need to do this. Can you just use a non-static class?

Comment: @Crowcoder I need this for configuring things in unit tests. I'd obviously never do this in production code. :)

Comment: Regardless, this is the recommended approach in many highly upvoted questions - but it doesn't work as expected. For that reason alone I'm very curious to learn why it fails.

Comment: Test frameworks, as far as I know, typically have a way to run code upon Test Initialize. See if you can use that to start fresh on your static class before each test case.

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks for that - yes that's what I typically do (lean on the test framework). But in this case I'm working with someone else's code and have to jump through hoops. In such cases reflection is quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, NET6 will not run the static constructor more than once no matter whether you use the TypeInitializer method or the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor method,
whereas Net Core and Net Framework will run it more than once.
I guess you could post a request on the dotnet runtime github project.